# Pandas DataFrame Apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with four columns, `A, B, C, D`.  It turns out that, sometimes, the values of `B` and `C` can be `0`.  I therefore wish to obtain the following:

```
B[i] = B[i] if B[i] else min(A[i], D[i])
C[i] = C[i] if C[i] else max(A[i], D[i])
```

where I have used `i` to indicate a run over all rows of the frame.  With Pandas it is easy to find the rows which contain zero columns:

```
df[df.B == 0] and df[df.C == 0]
```

however I have no idea how to easily perform the above transformation.  I can think of various inefficient and inelegant methods (`for` loops over the entire frame) but nothing simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A combination of boolean indexing and apply can do the trick.
Below an example on replacing zero element for column C.

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   A  B  C  D
0  8  3  5  8
1  9  4  0  4
2  5  4  3  8
3  4  8  5  1

In [23]: bi = df.C==0

In [24]: df.ix[bi, 'C'] = df[bi][['A', 'D']].apply(max, axis=1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   A  B  C  D
0  8  3  5  8
1  9  4  9  4
2  5  4  3  8
3  4  8  5  1
```

Comment: Quite neat.  However, I think that you can get away with `.max(axis=1)` instead of `apply(...)`.

Comment: `max()` is ok too of course, i think i got biased towards `apply` by the way you asked the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try 'iterrows' DataFrame class method for efficiently iterating through the rows of a DataFrame.See chapter 6.7.2 of the pandas 0.8.1 guide.

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np

df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3], 'B' : [0,0,0], 'C':[0,0,0], 'D' : [3,4,5]})

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 0:
        row['B'] = min(row['A'], row['D'])
    if row['C'] == 0:
        row['C'] = min(row['A'], row['D'])
```